# Regex_extract in hive to extract date

Tags: hive

I need help with `regex_extract` in Hive. I have string column from which I need to extract date. Sample data is given below

```
Abc def: 23-oct-17
Def:abc abc: 23-nov-2017
My data is: 17-nov-17
```

Comment: Can you highlight the full representation of a row and data it holds? It's not clear right away.

Comment: Can you please share the input (table/column) and the expected output?

Comment: Sample is for 3 different rows from the column from which I have to extract date.

Comment: The below are 3 different rows          Abc def: 23-oct-17

                       Def:abc abc: 23-nov-2017

                   My data is: 17-nov-17

Answer (score 0):

split() function is also regexp-based and you can split by semicolon+one or more spaces :

```
select
split(str,':\\s+')[1] date
from
(
select 
stack(3,
'Abc def: 23-oct-17',
'Def:abc abc: 23-nov-2017',
'My data is: 17-nov-17'
) as str
)s
```

Result:

```
OK
23-oct-17
23-nov-2017
17-nov-17
Time taken: 0.063 seconds, Fetched: 3 row(s)
```

Answer (score 0):

Since data is last part of the string, you can use below query

```
hive> select regexp_extract('Def:abc abc: 23-nov-2017', '\\d*-\\w*-\\d*$', 0);
OK
23-nov-2017
```

Above reg ex will match end of string with pattern DD-MON-YYYY